# Is there a way by which I can make my dropdown menu appear on the right using jquery mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to make dropdown right on the navbar.the problem is that the element always float left not right and also the css of li element is lost.
I'm missing something.
can anyone suggest for help
Thanks in advance.

header html

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="header">
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom" class="nav-custom">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="back" data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" data-theme="" data-icon="back">
                Back
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" id="bars" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="notext" data-iconshadow="false">&nbsp;</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
         </div>
        <ul id="menu-right">
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#a1">Option B1</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#a1">Option B2</a></li>
        </ul> 

</div>
```

javascript

```
     var windowWidth = (parseInt($(window).width())/2);
    $('#menu-right').css({'width': windowWidth});
    $('#bars').bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#menu-right").toggle();

    });
```

css

```
    #header #menu-right{        
    display: none; /* Hide */
    z-index:500; /* Ensure visibility over other elements on page */
    margin-top: 0px; /* Bring menu closer to button; not needed on mobile */
}
#header #menu-right li{

    display: block; /* JQM makes a inline-blocks... reset it to block */
}
#header  ul li a{
    white-space: normal; /* Stop long menu names from truncating */
}
#menu-right{
    position: absolute;
    float: right !important;
    margin-right:0.5em; 
}
```

here is the link of js file

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RddbW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS for #menu-right, rather use

```
right:0;
```

instead of

```
float: right !important;
```

Absolute positioning and floating does not work together.

To fix the CSS:

Add 
    data-role="listview" data-inset="true" 
to your ul called "menu-right".

Comment: i'm not getting css on dropdown list?

Comment: I was so .. just forgot  data-role="listview", :p
anyway thankx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move the #menu-right in the that plus li.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="bars" data-icon="custom" data-iconpos="notext" data-iconshadow="false">&nbsp;</a>
    <ul id="menu-right">
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#a1">Option B1</a></li>
        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#a1">Option B2</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
```

And change the css

```
#menu-right{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```